# Adding logic to extension

Tags: c#, google-chrome, timer

My question is about a chrome extension ,and want to add a c# application with that extension. is it possible? or else do i have any other way to add logic to my extension?

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is JS code insufficient for logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No it's not possible with C# only.**

A c# backend could be used to communicate with a database, or for performing tasks that cannot easily be performed client-side with JavaScript such as natural language processing or artificial intelligence.

What you would want to do is to code up some JavaScript that will communicate with a remote C# server through a REST interface. You are going to face the following barriers:

- loads of setup work
- You would be unable to display anything to the user with C#, it would be for processing logic/data only.
- You would have to pay money for a remote server or a static IP address.
- It would take just as much JavaScript to get this setup as it would to write a simple Chrome extension.
- You would have to figure out how to setup a C# server.

As you can see, if your just trying to write a simple extension, this isn't anything you want to have to deal with. There are, however, plenty of great tutorials that will show you how to create a Chrome extension with JavaScript.